# Ubuntu 20.04 screen flickering after power loss

Tags: 20.04, display, display-manager

I had Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS installed on my work machine for months and it worked without any problems. Yesterday the power suddenly went out in the office. After it came back and rebooting the machine, I started noticing weird flicking on the screen, in various random parts that it didn't look like a hardware issue. Examples:

- Disappearing "r" letter in one specific program only.
- The label of a folder on desktop appearing on top of applications I'm using.
- Ghost words/lines while typing in terminal.
- Certain parts in a webpage while browsing appear white, even when I scroll the page, makes me feel like it's a rendering issue.
- Sometimes the flickering happens on certain windows only, while other applications are rendered normally.

I tried restarting, complete shutdown, changing monitors, changing cables, switching to Wayland, disabling vsync. It's still happening, and it feels like an issue when I have around 4-8 applications opened at the same time.

Comment: I your system was not protected from a power outage by a UPS there may be problems system wise. See [this reference](https://tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/crash-repair.html).

Comment: Is it only on Linux or does it do this when you boot up into boot menu too? BIOS, etc.?  If not,  try to reinstall the drivers, or try another desk. Environment (IF this is the case)

Comment: These things happened after a power outage, but wasn't there also an software update? I've just read that some very recent kernel versions shipped with glitchy graphics (until they were withdrawn from distribution): https://askubuntu.com/q/1333025/1157519

Answer (score 2):

I would assume either the graphics driver or the physical graphics card took some damage.

If it's the driver, it could happen via disk problems (filesystem corruption), which is typical after non-graceful shutdowns (like power outages).

I would do this:

1. would **back up** all the important data/files from the computer to a safe storage
2. would **run** the **`fsck`** disk utility to find and correct possible filesystem corruptions (inconsistencies in the data recorded on the disk)

   - while this usually works well, it does not have a guaranteed 100% success rate; that's why the backup in the previous step
   - to check the `/` system partition, you need to boot from an Ubuntu live installer USB device, and use the "Try Ubuntu without installing" mode (or boot from a system rescue disk or similar); then find and mount your `/` partition, and run `fsck` from within this OS instance
3. if things don't improve after this, I would try **re-installing the graphics driver** somehow
4. if things would still not improve, there are still two checks you can carry out "for free":

   - **test the RAM** for any kind of defects: it's called `memtest`

     - it's available through a grub menu entry called *Memory test*, and and may take an hour or two
   - **test the internal disk** for any hardware-level defects, with a `SMART` self-test

     - for hard disks it's available e.g. through the `disks` app's "kebab menu"; for nvme SSDs it's a bit trickier, but legend has it that using `smartmontools` directly can do it
5. if nothing was found all through this while the errors persisted, then I would sadly conclude that the graphics card hardware (or the motherboard, even?) took physical damage...

Comment: This was quite a good answer, I would want to point out;  :thumbs up                         EDIT:  Yes of course,  no but  please,  even if you won't have any  URLS to ref. TO,  please still provide answers,  really good - and good luck on what you're up to! //Will

Comment: @WilliamMartens thank you! :) I wish I could have backed up all that with useful links, but I have a time budget to meet :)

Comment: Ah, one more last thing could be done before purchasing new hardware: You could try reinstalling the entire OS, in hopes that it makes the issue go away...