# Strange graphics issues such as flickering application windows and inconsistent display lagging

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, 20.10, display-manager, flicker

My computer was acting really strange; the windows were flickering and parts of windows of different applications were partly appearing at random places. Also when I was typing, my computer seemed to automatically selected text and copied it, but it could also be that it just duplicated a part of the screen of a few seconds ago. Hard to describe, but unworkable.

My Thinkpad carbon passed all hardware tests and I installed a fresh Ubuntu install. Still the same behavior. I found a solution that I wanted to share.

Comment: This question has also been asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331116/pc-started-having-screen-glitches-after-update/1332030#1332030).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The -49 and -50 kernels are flawed, and have been withdrawn. There are graphics issues (possibly only with internal Intel video subsystems).

Boot your computer. At the GRUB menu, select the 2nd choice, *Advanced Options* (or some such), and select your -48 kernel, or earlier if you don't have -48, and run off of that for now.

Keep up to date with Software Updater and once you see the -51 kernel, or later, then choose it at next boot.

**Update #1:**

Start Synaptic and install these files (search for 5.8.0-48)...

[image]

Run:

```
ls -al /boot
```

Confirm that `initrd.img-5.8.0-48-generic` is there.

If it's not there, then run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.8.0-48-generic
```

Then:

```
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

At the GRUB menu, select *Advanced Options*, then select the -48 kernel to boot from.

Comment: To install 5.8.0-48, I've typed out the info from your image for CLI oriented people: `sudo apt install linux-headers-5.8.0-48 linux-headers-5.8.0-48 linux-image-5.8.0-48-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-48-generic linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-48-generic`

Comment: @Ruben Did you do the rest of the commands? Are you now able to boot -48? You should probably answer via your original question.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you! I've updated my original question to link to this answer.

Comment: @Ruben Good! Did you remember to up-vote this answer for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: THIS SOLUTION DOES NOT WORK, ONLY TEMPORARY

However I found a very simple solution that I didn't find here so I want to share it. I needed to reconfigure my window manager. It are the first two steps of this [link](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/change-default-display-manager-ubuntu-20-04/)

1.) Check the current running display manager by running command:
`systemctl status display-manager.service`
[image]

2. Run command to reconfigure the default manager:
   `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

Where you replace `gdm3` with the manager you have at `Main PID:`

Comment: This doesn't sound right. The real problem is with kernel -49 and -50.

Comment: What doesnt sound right? It works perfectly again

Comment: When you reconfigured it, didn't it already have gdm3 selected?

Comment: Yes true it did

Comment: So you didn't really change anything. See my answer...

Comment: Show me `uname -r`.

Comment: `uname -r` gives 5.8.0-50-generic

Comment: Yes, you have one of the bad kernels. Do you still have -48 in /boot?

Comment: But how can it work again. I was also surprised. My laptop was really unworkable for days, and even a clean install didn't fix it. Since this it works

Comment: Try Firefox. My experience was that it was worse there. See Update #1 in my answer in case you don't have -48 any more.

Comment: Yes true I am on firefox now. That was worse. But now firefox runs smoothly. How do I check -48? Do i have to reboot?

Comment: In `terminal`, do `ls -al /boot`, and see if -48 is there. You may only see -49 and/or -50.

Comment: I see -50 and -25

Comment: If you're running ok now, no need to do anything, but if the problem returns, you'll have to do Update #1 to reinstall -48 and then boot to it... until they come out with a fixed kernel, which may be -51 or greater.

Comment: Have you rebooted yet?

Comment: I did now. It works well. But i guess I saw a small disturbance. But very small and not sure if that was related. If the strange behavior comes back I will give an update and apply your answer

Comment: Please do keep me posted. Start future comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Problem returned. Reconfiguration seemed to work again but only temporary. I will change the kernel as you proposed 

Comment: Check in your **Displays** settings panel, and tell me what choices you have for **Refresh rate**.

Comment: @heynnema 119.88, **59.97**, 59.95 or 59.82 Hz

Comment: Did you get the -48 kernel reinstalled and booted? The display should be fine if you did. If you're still running on -49 or -50, try different Refresh rates and see if it makes any difference on the video problem.

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks a lot