# Artifacts in display on Kubuntu 20.10

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, visual-artifacts

Since a few days, I'm seeing strange artifacts in Kubuntu 20.10 on both of my monitors. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHw84.jpg for two examples. Because I'm seeing it on both of my monitors and only while using Ubuntu (not Windows), I guess it is a software issue. Some info:

- Operating System: Kubuntu 20.10
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.5 KDE
- Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-3470S CPU @ 2.90GHz
- Memory: 15,5 GiB of RAM Graphics Processor:
- Mesa DRI Intel® HD Graphics 2500

Let me know if more info is required.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `uname -r` and `ls -al /boot`.

Comment: Kernels 5.8.0-49 and -50 are at fault. Boot to -48.

Comment: Indeed, I'm at 5.8.0-50-generic. I'll try and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately, when trying to boot from a reinstalled -48, I get stuck at "loading initial ram disk". Guess I'll wait for a fix?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /boot`. How did you reinstall -48? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333025/strange-graphics-issues-such-as-flickering-application-windows-and-inconsistent

Comment: Thanks @heynnema it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by [@heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema) in answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1333040/1282, many thanks!

Briefly,

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.8.0-48 linux-headers-5.8.0-48 linux-image-5.8.0-48-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-48-generic linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-48-generic
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.8.0-48-generic
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

Solved my issues for now, until -51 is available.