# Pixels in selected text show the wrong colour

Tags: graphics, 21.04

I installed Ubuntu 21.04 and I got this problem:
[image]

Actually this happens in other places of ubuntu as well.

Comment: This looks like system requirements of something. Why do you think this is a bug? Which text did you select?

Comment: have you entered something in the Chromium browser search bar that it is responding to? Please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: No no. Look to the selected box. It's like a problem. pay attention

Comment: It looks like some of the pixels, that should be blue, are in fact white. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly. Yes! That's what I mean.

Comment: May be related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334681/artifacts-in-display-on-kubuntu-20-10

Comment: Graphics driver issue?

Comment: Thanks! I'll test it.

Comment: Ah yes, the faulty kernel.