# Glitching screens, worse when using firefox, and the letter f doesn't show in settings page. ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, graphics, firefox, amd-graphics

Two days ago my screen went crazy. I have two monitors, and it happens on both. From freezing, to flickering, glitching, random texts disappearing and reappearing on webpages, plus, on my settings page it should, for example, "De. ault Applications", "Fire. ox", etc, with the small letter f being substituted by a dot, but only in parts of the text. My specifications are Intel® Core™ i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4 ,Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2),memory 15.3 GiB,Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, Windowing system X11,GNOME version 3.36.3

This started happening after an update, but I didn't find ways to fix this. Can anyone help me on what could be causing this?

Comment: You're probably running on the 5.8.0.-49 or -50 kernel. Do `uname -r` to check. It's bugged. Boot to -48 and wait for an update to -51 or later.

Comment: I updated to 5.12.1-051201-generic and it worked! thank you

Comment: 5.12.1 is a test kernel, and really shouldn't be run except to test with. You'd do better to wait for the official -51 kernel, and run on -48 for now.

Comment: Ok, this will be a probably dumb question, but how do I do that? I searched about booting to -48, kernel versions and all, but I only found of how to choose a version to install, such as v5.8.0, but not how to specify either -48,-49,-50 ... I don't understand which kernel to install then

Comment: Boot to GRUB menu. Choose Advanced Options. Select the -48 (or earlier) kernel. You can also see my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333025/strange-graphics-issues-such-as-flickering-application-windows-and-inconsistent